# Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: visual-studio, отладка

Как отключить заход в библиотеки?
Выполняю код, нажимая f10, и когда ошибка, например, в векторе, он переходит в библиотеку vector, как это можно отключить? То есть чтобы при возникновении ошибки он оставался на той же строке в моем, где она возникла, и ничего не открывал?

Comment: По стектрейсу в таком случае до вашего кода поднимитесь и все.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов можно поподробнее?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов нашел, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По стектрейсу в таком случае до вашего кода поднимитесь и все. Вряд ли возможно отключение этой фичи.